# How can i make PHP to wait for a variable to be initialized?

Tags: php, html

I need a PHP block to be run only when a variable is already set, do i need to do something with JavaScript or PHP is able to do it?
Details: My variable is only set when the HTML form is submitted.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    $caminho = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $data->read("$caminho");

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pessoas");
    mysqli_select_db($conn,"pessoas");

    for ($x = 1; $x <= count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) {
        $nome = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
        $matricula = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][2];
        $nascimento = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][3];
        $celular = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][4];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO info (nome,matricula,datanasc,celular) 
        VALUES ('$nome','$matricula','$nascimento','$celular')";
    echo $sql."\n";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);}
    }else {
    echo "Selecione um arquivo v&aacute;lido";
    }
```

Comment: please post some code and show us where you specific problem is

Comment: Would love to see your code. Here's a hint : http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: I used the empty() and it worked!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the variable was set using the function [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
  if(isset($var)){
      // do something
  }
```

Comment: you should only use isset() in this case

Comment: @swidmann Why? `empty` will check to see if it is set and has a value in it.

Comment: @Styphon just for example: `$var=0`, isset would return true `!empty` would return false. because the var isset but 0 in this case is empty, even an **empty** string is empty, although the var isset

Comment: you are right, folks. empty() is not appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try using **isset()** function.

```
if( isset( $your_variable ) ) 
{
  #your code here...this block works only if '$your_variable' is set..
 } else { #do nothing. }
```